# X-Editable checklist displayed horizontally

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, x-editable

I made a checklist using xeditable (http://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/docs.html), and the script is shown below and is also located at https://jsfiddle.net/m8L2hyko/.

```
<a href="#" id="options" data-type="checklist" data-pk="1" data-url="/post" data-title="Select options"></a>

$('#options').editable({
  value: [2, 3],
  source: [ {value: 1,text: 'option1'}, {value: 2,text: 'option2'}, {value: 3,text: 'option3'}]
});
```

The plugin replaces the `<a>` element with the following HTML.

```
<a data-title="Select options" data-url="/post" data-pk="1" data-type="checklist" id="options" href="#" class="editable editable-click">
  option2<br>option3
</a>
```

As seen, `<br>` elements are inserted between each selected option.  Instead of displaying it as a vertical list with line breaks, I would like to display them as a horizontal comma separated list such as "option2, option3".

How is this possible?

Comment: It is .. You are going to have to download `jqueryui-editable.js` instead of calling to it from the CDN.  and edit the JS yourself ... Just do a "find" and search for 'br'  ..  It's pretty extensive, but entirely possible.

Comment: @Zak  Was hoping not to go that route from a maintainability perspective.  Instead, maybe use CSS to make a `<br>` appear as a space?  I know I said comma separated, but spaces would also be okay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the display option.

```
  display: function(value, sourceData) {
    //display checklist as comma-separated values
    var html = [],
      checked = $.fn.editableutils.itemsByValue(value, sourceData);

    if (checked.length) {
      $.each(checked, function(i, v) {
        html.push($.fn.editableutils.escape(v.text));
      });
      $(this).html(html.join(', '));
    } else {
      $(this).empty();
    }
  }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/m8L2hyko/3/

Answer (score 0):

Looks like changing the content in CSS work for chrome.

```
#options br {
  content: "";
}
#options br:after {
  content: ", ";
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/8hcrxa95/

Comment: Works with Chrome, but not FF.  Not sure about IE.  I can use `display:none`, but then there is no space between them.  Maybe somehow padding/margin could be used, but don't think so.

Comment: The javascript approach probably makes more sense and would be consistent across all browsers. I found the idea of overriding the br intriguing and wondered if it was possible using CSS alone.